# Docker Network Namespace

Tags: docker

I'm using docker ubuntu:quantal

It seems that network namespaces is not enabled. How can I enable network namespaces?

root@e5e9957daa67:~# ip netns add blue

Failed to create a new network namespace: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're running in a container. If you want to be able to handle namespaces and such, your container has to be started with the `-privileged` flag.

Comment: Tip: there are two hyphens.